# WooCommerce with HPOS hiding completed order rows?

Tags: woocommerce

In wooCommerce with HPOS enabled, how do you hide completed orders from the main admin order list?

I previously used the solution below, but it uses the old method of storing orders in posts.

```
/**
* Hide completed orders from admin order list
*/
function action_parse_query( $query ) { 
global $pagenow;

// Your order status to hide, must start with 'wc-'
$hide_order_status = 'wc-cancelled';
$hide_order_status2 = 'wc-completed';
$hide_order_status3 = 'wc-failed';

// Initialize
$query_vars = &$query->query_vars;

// Only on WooCommerce admin order list
if ( $pagenow == 'admin.php' && $query_vars['page'] == 'wc-orders' ) {
    
// Finds whether a variable is an array
if ( is_array( $query_vars['post_status'] ) ) {  

// Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful
if ( ( $key = array_search( $hide_order_status, $query_vars['post_status'] ) ) !== false ) {

unset( $query_vars['post_status'][$key] );
}

if ( ( $key = array_search( $hide_order_status2, $query_vars['post_status'] ) ) !== false ) {
unset( $query_vars['post_status'][$key] );
}

if ( ( $key = array_search( $hide_order_status3, $query_vars['post_status'] ) ) !== false ) {
unset( $query_vars['post_status'][$key] );
}

}

}

}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'action_parse_query', 10, 1 );
```